# Get a particular position in string outside HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string

I have a below string:

```text
<span class="badge bg-teal black bg-lighten-4">2023-03-29 15:37:34 (Admin): </span>
he like to visit today call back him 5.30pm for confirmation. <br/>
<span class="badge bg-teal black bg-lighten-4">2023-03-29 15:37:34 (An): </span>
he will come for visit. <br/>
```

I want a position/index outside the `<span>…</span>` or `<br>` element  after 160 characters.

My current approach:

```js
var string = $('.string').html().toString();
var pos = 160;
var condition1 = false;
var condition2 = false;
while(pos < string.length){
    for(var i = pos; i >=0; i--){
        if(string.substring(i,7) == "</span>"){
            condition1 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(var j = pos; j <string.length; i++){
        if(string.substring(i,5) == '<span'){
          condition2 = true;
          break;
        }
    }
    if(condition1 == true && condition2 == true){
        break;
    }
    pos++;
}
console.log(pos);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="string" style="display:none;">
  <span class="badge bg-teal black bg-lighten-4">2023-03-29 15:37:34 (Admin): </span>
  he like to visit today call back him 5.30pm for confirmation. <br/>
  <span class="badge bg-teal black bg-lighten-4">2023-03-29 15:37:34 (An): </span>
  he will come for visit.  <br/>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest the javascript/jquery code?

Comment: you mean want to get `innerText`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you expect the end result to be?  Ignoring the `<span>` and `<br>` your text has less than 100 characters, so there isn't a "position after 160 characters" (as I *interpret* your vague requirement).     If you could say "given this HTML, the result would be 200" it might be possible to reverse-engineer your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the philosophy that the [browser's HTML parser is superior to homemade stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), you can let the browser repair it, simply by assigning the truncated string to an element's `innerHTML`. Since browser will provide a closing tag if one is elided, if the repaired HTML is longer than the max length, then we must cut off the last element.

```js
function xify(text, maxlen) {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  maxlen ??= 160
  div.innerHTML = text.substring(0, maxlen)
  if (div.innerHTML.length > maxlen) {
    div.removeChild(div.lastChild)
  }
  return div.innerHTML
}

const text = `  <span class="badge bg-teal black bg-lighten-4">2023-03-29 15:37:34 (Admin): </span>
  he like to visit today call back him 5.30pm for confirmation. <br/>
  <span class="badge bg-teal black bg-lighten-4">2023-03-29 15:37:34 (An): </span>
  he will come for visit.  <br/>`
console.log(240, xify(text, 240))
console.log(235, xify(text, 235))
console.log(160, xify(text))
console.log(156, xify(text, 156))
console.log(155, xify(text, 155))
console.log(154, xify(text, 154))
```